# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. InvalidOperation: (GetAssociationByName:String)

Tags: powershell

When trying to run this Powershell Script I'm getting an error:

```
Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [alias("url")]
        $siteurl,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [alias("list")]
        $listname,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [alias("workflow")]
        $workflowname
        )

    $site = Get-SPSite $siteurl
    $web = $site.RootWeb;
    $list = $web.Lists[$listname];
    $statusChoices = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($workflowname,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).BaseTemplate.GetStatusChoices($web);

    $countChoices = $statusChoices.count;

    Write-Host 'Status Choice count - ' $countChoices;

    $i = 0;

    while($i -lt $countChoices)
    {
      Write-Host $i ' - ' $statusChoices[$i];
      $i++;
    }
```

Error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\PowerShellScript\test.ps1:12 char:65
+ $statusChoices = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName <<<< ($workf
lowname,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).BaseTemplate.GetSta
tusChoices($web)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetAssociationByName:String)
   [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: did you specify all parameters (`$siteurl`, `$listname` and `$workflowname`) in command line properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$web = $site.OpenWeb();
```

Changing these two lines helped.